# Can't use WPToolkit in XAML

Tags: xaml, wptoolkit, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I currently get following error:
 `error : The tag 'ListPicker' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Toolkit'.`
The XAML is following:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker />
```

The xml namespace is:
`xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Toolkit"`

I have found similar problems where the dll was not existent or blocked. This is not the case in this time. I can use the controls from code but not XAML. I also tied a clean and rebuild. But it didn't helped.

The problem is not only ListPicker but every control in the toolkit xml namespace. (including no autocompleting)

The Project is a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the declare the following namespace:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

I can't test it right now! :-S